# How to bind EF dataSet with WPF datagrid?

Tags: wpf, linq, entity-framework, datagrid, dataset

I can't connect properly my dataSet (from EF) with WPF datagrid. My issue is that my datagrid shows :

- two selected column with correct column header (great :-) ! )
- all other column (including two above) with column header from database (I don't want theses columns)

Here is my code :

```
<DataGrid  Name="dataGridDomaines" Grid.Row="4" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom Domaine" Width="300" Binding="{Binding Path=NomDomaine}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° Inter" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=idOpérateur}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And :

```
private void Rechercher(string elementARechercher){
        using (CaveAVinContext ctx = new CaveAVinContext())
        {
            //recherche des domaines
            var domaines = ctx.Domaines
                .Where(a => a.NomDomaine.Contains(elementARechercher))
                .ToList();
            dataGridDomaines.ItemsSource = domaines;
            lblDomaines.Content = "Domaine(s) : " + domaines.Count + " resultat(s)";


        }
    }
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) property of a `DataGrid` is true, which will cause it to append all of the columns to the end of whatever you've specified directly.

Just set that to false and you should be good to go.

```
<DataGrid  Name="dataGridDomaines" Grid.Row="4" 
       IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
       AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom Domaine" Width="300" Binding="{Binding Path=NomDomaine}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="N° Inter" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=idOpérateur}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `Datagrid` `Autogeneratecolumns` to `False`.
* Note that The default value for this property is `True`.